# If two sources add entry to SQL table at the same time will they both get added with 'ADD UNIQUE'?

Tags: php, android, sql

I have code similar to the following:

```
$sql2 = "ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE(field2, feild3, field4, field5);";    
$sql2 .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO table (field1, field2, feild3, field4, field5) VALUES ('$_POST[field1]','$_POST[field2]','$_POST[field3]','$_POST[field4]','$_POST[field5]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql2,$con))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";
}
```

I have found that I get an error if the table already has two rows which are the same but works well otherwise. I am worried that if I add the duplicates from two different sources that they will both be added to the table and later requests will trigger the error I got earlier because of the two almost identical rows. Is it possible to add two almost identical rows as shown above if the php file is executed at the same time from two different sources?

EDIT: FYI The code is a snippet from a larger program. I am sending data from an android app I am working on to the $_POST fields

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but based on my personal experience and just by looking at your code, I think you are doing it wrong. Why do you need to alter the design of your table every time you insert a record into the table? Altering table should be avoided at run-time for this kind of stuff. Also inserting POST data directly into a SQL statement is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. mysql_query DOES NOT ALLOW execute two queries in single call
2. insert ignore won't return error when duplicate found (that's why it named as ignore)

So, the FIRST error is caused by the `alter ...; insert ...`

Then alter table is require execute once only,
on your next execution, you are no longer require to perform alter table (again).
Otherwise, you will getting the duplicate INDEX error (trying to add an existing index)

For the unique index, is meant to prevent duplicate,
so, it only will have one unique record (no matter what)

And for you funny *almost identical*,
it will never happen

it blocked when duplication found on field 2..5

Comment: FYI When I said "almost identical" I was referring each row since I did not include field1 in the key

Comment: you misunderstood, you can't have two records with identical value of field 2,3,4,5

Comment: I know. I wrote "almost identical" because of the key. I am worried about rows with identical values in fields 2-5. I don't care if field 1 is a duplicate or not.

Comment: I am still wondering: is it possible to execute this code from two phones at the exact same time and add two "almost identical" or identical rows because the php script is checking, at the same time, if the row already exists and at the moment it does not so identical rows are added?

Comment: seems like you don't get the picture. Where an unique field is defined, it will NOT tolerant for two rows with identical value (field 2..5). So, there will only one row get inserted even two insertion took place at the same time.

Comment: It's not possible to have identical rows, but yes.. 2 almost identical rows can exist and are NOT Identical

Comment: STOP thinking 2 almost identical rows, is identical (after-all) because unique column is defined on field 2 to 5.

Comment: yes, i should have just written identical. I think that would have been a bit clearer

Answer (score 2):

What does the table DDL look like? The way to control duplicates is using keys on your table that allow/disallow records based on that key structure. There is no such thing in SQL as "almost identical" they are either duplicates or unique.

When working with Db's and updates you should always build the update/delete/modify constraints within the DDL. Therefore it should not matter what or how many processes are trying to modify the DB.. The DB will manage the updates using table locks etc.. and will manage the updates to the table based on your constraints.

If you have more questions or this did not help, please post you table DDL.

Comment: I mean "almost identical" for each row because the unique key does not specify field1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "almost identical rows". Rows are either identical or not. If you are referring to your UNIQUE criteria, again rows are either unique based on the criterial specified or not.

At the time the INSERT command is being executed, if there is already a UNIQUE constraint in place by the same PHP script or another PHP script, and the row being inserted violates the UNIQUE constraint, the second query will be rejected even if it's a fraction of seconds after the first query. If they are not identical, doesn't matter who asks for the query or how many pages are involved, it goes through.